# Google Map Fail to load in iOS with error -999

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have integrated google map SDK in my application. It was running fine and two days back I updated the SDK by pod, After that map is not loading.
Whenever I load View Controller with map it shows me empty map without any location and In console following error throws:

```
ClientParametersRequest failed, 5 attempts remaining (0 vs 7). Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://clients4.google.com/glm/mmap, NSLocalizedDescription=cancelled, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://clients4.google.com/glm/mmap}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I found why it is not loading map. Actually My device time is set to future and every google request is failed in that case.

Comment: I was facing same issue. how can we used when user change the device time and come back to the application. google API also not working.